# how to edit the cart page? checkout_cart_index magento 2

Tags: magento2

How to edit a cart page? checkout_car_index. Every time I edit the layout, the value next to the freight and the discount value as well. It seems that it is not possible to move on that page correctly. Can someone help me? The code is the same standard code as in the vendor. Does magento have any rules in checkout_cart_index? because every time I move a block, the freight cost stops showing up.

Comment: Update question with code you have tried so far.